# Highlight table rows

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to for table row highlight. Here is my code:

```
$('table#results tr').mouseover(function() {
  var color = $(this).css("background-color")
 $(this).css("background-color","yellow !important");
}).mouseout(function() {
 $(this).css("background-color", ""+color+" !important");
});
```

My goal is to keep original color of row in variable. The color variable is not accessible within mouseout method (I believe because of scope rules).
My question is what to do so color var to be accessible in mouseout method ?

Comment: You should declare the original color in an external CSS selector and the change it with jQuery, that way you don't need to keep the previous color. It also makes your HTML less evil.

Comment: If you just need to highlight hovered row use CSS, no need of javascipt at all.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with pure CSS, which in my opinion is a much better solution:

```
table#results tr:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Just because you add :hover to a selector, that doesn't mean that the selector chain has to stop there. This is a nice, and much cleaner way of highlighting table rows than having to do all this crazy stuff with JavaScript and classes just to add a background to table cells on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class instead, then remove it when not needed.

```
$(function() {
    $('table#results tr').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});
```

And then in CSS:

```
.hover { background-color: yellow !important; }
```